# Excel resize cell according to image size

Tags: c#, .net, excel, image

I am inserting an image in an excel cell, but usually that image will be larger, both in height and in width than the original cell. So after I have inserted my image I would like to: resize the specific excel row and column according to the image's size. This is what I have:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@".../MyExcelFile.xlsx");
        ws = wb.Sheets[1];

        string picPath = @"..../MyPic.png";

        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(picPath);
        var size = img.Size;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ws.Cells[1, 5];
        float Left = (float)((double)oRange.Left);
        float Top = (float)((double)oRange.Top);
        const float ImageSize = 32;
        ws.Shapes.AddPicture(picPath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, ImageSize, ImageSize);
```

So here I am inserting my image in the 5th cell of the 1st row, but setting its size to 32.However, I have access to this image's height and width. How can I set row 1 to that height and column 5 to that width?

EDIT: With the current code from Richard Mneyan, it looks like this, so the image doesn't fit in the cell: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below would set height and width of your cell to respective picture height and width if you apply ratio of Column widths to Row Heights:

```
    var sh = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(picPath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, ImageSize, ImageSize);
    oRange.Rows[1].RowHeight = sh.Height;
    oRange.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = sh.Width;
```

This is not perfect answer because it is really hard to set Excel Column Widths to exact number. For instance the default Excel Column width is 8.43, the next increment would be 8.57. Why?; because it is based on number of the Normal font 
characters that can fit in a cell: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214123/description-of-how-column-widths-are-determined-in-excel

Here applying approximate ratios (which is not perfect):

```
        double rColRow = 6; // Ratio of units of measure: columns widths to row heights
        double rImgColWidth = 5.9; // Ratio of units of measure: image size and column widths

        oRange.Rows[1].RowHeight = (sh.Width * rColRow / rImgColWidth);
        oRange.Columns[1].ColumnWidth = (sh.Height / rImgColWidth);
```

Comment: Thanks, this does change the height and width of the first row, but now the image doesn't fit well in the cell. Check my edit to see how it looks like.

Comment: The units of RowHeight of Excel and ColumnWidth of Excel are not the same units. Setthing RowHeight of 32 and ColumnWidth of 32 would not make cell square in Excel. Here an article how you can apply ration to make it square: https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/exact-ratio-of-width-to-height-to-get-a-square-cell.3454558/

Comment: You would need to apply ration along with height and width: https://superuser.com/questions/165738/how-to-make-cells-perfect-squares-in-excel this link would help.